# How do you play the vendettas?

Tags: the-darkness-2

Now that I finished the game, I'd like to explore additional gameplay and content. I know there is a co-op mode called `vendettas`.

Do them extend the story? or are they sandboxes?
How is the gameplay, what do you need cooperation for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story line of the Vendetta campaign is parallel to the main campaign. For example, it's you who retrieves Johnny Powell for Jackie Estacado at the start of the game. The rest of the campaign mainly revolves around retrieving relics from the Brotherhood.

There's also Hit List exclusive missions, which are isolated as far as story goes. Mostly they are variations on existing maps.

The gameplay is pretty straightforward. You play as one of the 4 playable characters, who each has their own innate talent, signature weapon, and Darkness power (you don't have them all, like Jackie does).

Cooperation isn't really needed at all, but of course it helps. There's 2 main reasons for it:

1. If you die, other players can revive you (unless you bleed out). Playing alone, you start over at a checkpoint.
2. It makes the game easier. The number and strength of enemies doesn't seem to scale all that much, if at all. In addition, every character, if upgraded, emits an aura that buffs a certain stat on their team mates.

Oh, and there are a few Hit List missions that *require* a second player. Not because they're exceptionally difficult, but because the game won't let you play them otherwise.

Comment: Nice. I love when they complement the story... like in `Enter the matrix` and `Resident evil 2`

Comment: @JuanManuel It doesn't really do that all that much. Most of the campaign is about chasing the Spear of Destiny, which is apparently a real threat to Jackie, but I don't think it's ever mentioned in the single player campaign.